# ActiveX component can't create object VBA runtime error

Tags: c#, vba, excel

**STEP 1:** creating Excel 2010 add-in

I created a new project, Excel 2010 add-in, .Net 4 framework

I added a class file to it "Name.cs", interface "iName.cs" and added a function to it

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface iName
{
string getName();
}
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Name 
{
public string getName()
{
 return "Hello";
} 
}
```

**STEP 2:** Configuring build events

I configured the build events of the pro

```
"%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase /tlb 
"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll"
```

This will register the Dll so that it will be available in the `references` column in the Excel

**STEP 3:**  Adding reference in Excel macro

I created a module, in the tools-> reference I added the `NameProvider` (name of that assembly/project) add-in that is available after I built the Excel add-in project

I tried to create an object for that added reference

```
Public Sub test()
Dim nameObj as NameProvider.Name
Dim name as string
Set nameObj = new NameProvider.Name  'error 429 occurs here
name = nameObj.getName()  'getName function automatically comes after .
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using Office 64bit?

Comment: Yes its 64 bit @dePatinkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Office 64bit you need to compile your assembly as x64 compatible, and register it with the 64bit framework by using the **regasm** from the Framework**64** folder.

```
"%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase /tlb 
"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll"
```

%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm -> %Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework**64**\v4.0.30319\regasm

Comment: thanks!!
what modification should i do if i want it to work for 32 bit os as well?

Comment: You need to compile for Any CPU and create a separate registration process for each platform.